# Accessing object inside array in Javascript is returning TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, google-apps-script

I'm trying to access an object inside of an array of objects using javascript in Google Apps Script, but it's giving me an error - TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The JSON (received from an API result) is as follows, and is stored in the "data" variable:

```
[{
    "values": {
        "article_number": [
            {
                "locale": null,
                "scope": null,
                "data": "000000000010137290"
            }
        ],
        "article_description": [
            {
                "locale": null,
                "scope": null,
                "data": "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser 3 Draw Sil"
            }
        ],
        "marketing_description": [
            {
                "locale": "en_US",
                "scope": null,
                "data": "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser and 3 Drawers Mesh Silver"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

I'm trying to access the "data" element and add each data element to a new object:

```
var product = [];
  data.forEach(function(elem,i) {
    products.push(
     {
      article_number:elem["article_number"][0]["data"],
      article_description:elem["article_description"][0]["data"],
      marketing_description:elem["marketing_description"][0]["data"]
     });
  });
```

I would really appreciate the assistance in solving this. I've tried removing the [0], but this just returns the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined". I'm at my whits end, as I assumed that calling index 0 of the array would work.

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: I would like to see an object: 

{
article_number: "000000000010137290",
article_description:"SDS Mini Desktop Organiser 3 Draw Sil",
marketing_description:"SDS Mini Desktop Organiser and 3 Drawers Mesh Silver"
} This would loop through the initial object and create a new simpler object with only the values required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit more verbose than what you were going for, but here's what I did.

1. Iterate through the keys of the object.
2. Find the `data` property of the matching object.
3. Create a new object with pairs in the format of `key: data`.

**Output:**

```json
[
  {
    "article_number": "000000000010137290",
    "article_description": "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser 3 Draw Sil",
    "marketing_description": "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser and 3 Drawers Mesh Silver"
  }
]
```

**Full code below:**

```js
let recieved = [{
  values: {
    article_number: [{
      locale: null,
      scope: null,
      data: "000000000010137290",
    }, ],
    article_description: [{
      locale: null,
      scope: null,
      data: "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser 3 Draw Sil",
    }, ],
    marketing_description: [{
      locale: "en_US",
      scope: null,
      data: "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser and 3 Drawers Mesh Silver",
    }, ],
  },
}, ];

let allValues = [];

for (let i = 0; i < recieved.length; i++) {

  let newObj = Object.keys(recieved[i].values).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = recieved[i].values[curr][0].data;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  allValues.push(newObj);
}

console.log(allValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data1 = [{
    "values": {
        "article_number": [
            {
                "locale": null,
                "scope": null,
                "data": "000000000010137290"
            }
        ],
        "article_description": [
            {
                "locale": null,
                "scope": null,
                "data": "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser 3 Draw Sil"
            }
        ],
        "marketing_description": [
            {
                "locale": "en_US",
                "scope": null,
                "data": "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser and 3 Drawers Mesh Silver"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
var product = []; 
data1.forEach(function (elem, i) { 
product.push({ 
article_number: elem.values["article_number"][0]["data"], 
article_description: elem.values['article_description'][0].data, 
marketing_description: elem.values['marketing_description'][0].data });
}); 
console.log(product)
```

```js
let data1 = [{
    "values": {
        "article_number": [
            {
                "locale": null,
                "scope": null,
                "data": "000000000010137290"
            }
        ],
        "article_description": [
            {
                "locale": null,
                "scope": null,
                "data": "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser 3 Draw Sil"
            }
        ],
        "marketing_description": [
            {
                "locale": "en_US",
                "scope": null,
                "data": "SDS Mini Desktop Organiser and 3 Drawers Mesh Silver"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
var product = [];
data1.forEach(function (elem, i) {
    product.push({ article_number: elem.values.article_number[0].data, article_description: elem.values.article_description[0].data, marketing_description: elem.values.marketing_description[0].data });
});
console.log(product)
```

Comment: I unfortunately still get the same error :(

Comment: Your above code doesn't have elem.values..... did you correct that